# How to run one update and commit in single command in ORACLE

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I want to run a update query in ORACLE but to reflect the change of that query (means updating the value in database with receptive values) i have to run a **commit;** after that query (then only the value change will be updated in the database). So, how can i pass the update statement and the commit in same line through C#.

i am running the query like below,

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET columnname1 = 'N', 
       columnname2 = 1
 WHERE columnname3 = '-2085371064';

COMMIT;
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying *"reflect the change of that query"* ?

Comment: Are you sure that `columnname3` is of type `Char` \ `VarChar2`?  `columnname3  = '-2085371064'`? It seems it should be `columnname3  = -2085371064` (no apostrophes)

Comment: Usually, you don't want *explict* `commit`: all the changes will be applied by *autocommit* when you close the connection.

Comment: @eocron have updated the question.

Comment: @DMitryBychenko but in my connection i think we have to explicitly call the commit to reflect the update command changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you are using ADO.NET, you can make use of Commit() method:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    OracleTransaction transaction;

    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    try
    {
        command.CommandText = 
            "UPDATE table_name    SET columnname1 = 'N',        columnname2 = 1 WHERE columnname3 = '-2085371064';";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't want *explicit* `commit` since all the changes will be *auto commited* on the connection close. However, if you insist on `COMMIT` you can do it with a help of Oracle's *anonymous block*:

```
 //TODO: put the right connection here
 using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
   con.Open();

   string sql = 
     @"BEGIN -- Anonymous block: run these queries (update, commit) together
         UPDATE table_name 
            SET columnname1 = 'N', 
                columnname2 = 1
          WHERE columnname3 = '-2085371064'; -- Is it really a string?

         COMMIT; -- Not necessary, but possible
       END;";

   using (var q = con.CreateCommand()) {
     q.CommandText = sql;

     q.ExecuteNonQuery();   
   } 
 }
```